# WTForms render_field() method reference for-loop variables

Tags: python, validation, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm using Flask to create a web app. I'm trying to create a form using Flask-WTForms by iterating through a list passed in the `render_template()` method. However, I can't reference the variable in the for-loop inside the template.

**View**

```
class FormExample(Form):
    category1 = StringField("Category 1")
    category2 = StringField("Category 2")

categories = ['category1', 'category2']
def form():
    form = FormExample(request.form)
    return_template("form.html", categories=categories, form=form)
```

**_formhelpers.html** (suggested to use under the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/wtforms/))

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

**Template (form.html)**

```
<form method="POST">
  {% for category in categories %}
    {{render_field(form.category)}}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

When trying to reference `form.category` in `form.html` I'm given the following error through the Flask debugger:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: '__main__.EvaluateCaseForm object' has no attribute 'category'
```

I've already looked at the official documentation [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#) and couldn't find the answer. I've also tried referencing `{{render_field({{ form.category }})}}`, `{{render_field(form.{{category}})}}`, and `{{render_field({% form.category %})}}`

Is there a way to reference the for-loop variable `category` inside the `render_field()` method?

Comment: Why not `{% for field in form %}{{ render_field(field) }}{% endfor %}`?  Are you trying to handle `categories` not matching the fields in your form?

Comment: @snakecharmerb the issue I'm having is that `form.category` is being read as though the variable `form` has an attribute called `category`. However, I want the value for `category` to be the value based on the for-loop. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTForms uses the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) protocol to allow fields can be accessed like [dictionary values](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#wtforms.form.BaseForm.__getitem__), for example `form[fieldname]`.

So in your code, replace `form.category` with `form[category]`:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% for category in categories %}
    {{ render_field(form[category]) }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to reference the for-loop variable category inside the render_field() method?

Yup:

```
   {% for category in categories %}
     {{render_field(category)}}
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I apologize I don't think I made myself clear. I need to access the form attributes `form.category1` and `form.category2`. I just updated the question with a bit more information to hopefully make it more clear. Trying to pass in `(category)` just passes in a string and not a form attribute.